# Base de datos con mongoDb angular y node.js

Tags: nodejs, angular, base-de-datos, mongodb

estoy intentando crear un metodo post para mi pagina, basicamente lo que quiero es que se puedan agregar nuevos productos por parte del usuario para mostrar en la web, pero no comprendo porque estoy teniendo el mismo error por mas que intento arreglarlo. Este es mi codigo.

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const express = require('express');
const { Product } = require('./modelProduct');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const uri = "aqui puse mi uri, pero la quito por seguridad :) ";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: false,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  }
});

const app = express();
const port = 4001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let database; // Variable para la base de datos
let collection; // Variable para la colección de productos

async function run() {
  try {
    // Conectar a la base de datos
    await client.connect();
    console.log("Conexión exitosa a la base de datos");

    // Seleccionar la base de datos y la colección
    database = client.db("products");
    collection = database.collection("productsCollection");

    // Iniciar el servidor Express
    app.post('/api/products', (req, res) => {
      const productData = req.body;
  
      if (!productData.title || !productData.alt || !productData.category) {
          res.status(400).json({ error: 'Title, alt, and category are mandatory fields.' });
      } else {
          const newProduct = new Product({
              title: productData.title,
              alt: productData.alt,
              description: productData.description || '123-456', // Use a default value if not provided
              image: productData.image || [], // Use an empty array if not provided
              category: productData.category,
              price: productData.price || 100 // Use a default value if not provided
          });
  
          newProduct.save((err, savedProduct) => {
              if (err) {
                  res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create a new product.' });
              } else {
                  res.status(201).json(savedProduct);
              }
          });
      }
  });
    // Ruta para obtener todos los productos
    
    app.get('/productos', async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const products = await collection.find({}).toArray();

        res.json(products);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error al obtener productos:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Error al obtener productos" });
      }
    });
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Servidor Express iniciado en el puerto ${port}`);
    });
  } finally {
    
  }
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```

Este es mi product.service

```
// product.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product, ProductItem } from '../models/product.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:4001/productos';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProducts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}`);
  }

  addProduct(product: Product): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}`, product, { withCredentials: true });
  }

}
```

y este es el ts de mi componente donde hago la peticion para hacer el post

```
// product-form.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-product',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
})
export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit {
  products!: FormGroup; // Declarar el tipo de FormGroup

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.products = this.formBuilder.group({
      alt: 'hola',
      id: 0,
      title: 'hola',
      price: 0,
      category: 'hola',
      description: 'hola',
      image: [['asdasd','asdasd']],
    });
  }
  
  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log('Enviando solicitud...');
    const newProduct: Product = this.products.value;
    console.log('Datos del formulario:', newProduct);
 
    this.productService.addProduct(this.products.value).subscribe({
       next: (response: any) => {
          console.log('Producto agregado exitosamente:', response);
       },
       error: (error: any) => {
          console.error(this.products.value);
          console.error('Error al agregar el producto:', error);
       },
       complete: () => {
          // Puedes realizar acciones cuando la suscripción se complete (opcional)
       }
    });
 }
}
```

y este es el error que obtengo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRjK0.png)
me serviria mucho su ayuda :)))

intente cambiar el cors ya que lei que era el problema pero no encontre una solucion clara que pudiera implementar, lo que me gustaria es que se pudiera hacer el post hacia mi base de datos.